# C2039 and C2873 when including `<cctype>` from the STL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a project with msvc 2019 compilers that I know has been compiled before. In fact, I'm actually updating the build system for it. I've come across a strange problem with sources from the standard template library. Basically the project includes `<cctype>` which pulls in the following snippet:

```
_STD_BEGIN
using _CSTD isalnum;
using _CSTD isalpha;
using _CSTD iscntrl;
using _CSTD isdigit;
using _CSTD isgraph;
using _CSTD islower;
using _CSTD isprint;
using _CSTD ispunct;
using _CSTD isspace;
using _CSTD isupper;
using _CSTD isxdigit;
using _CSTD tolower;
using _CSTD toupper;

using _CSTD isblank;
_STD_END
```

But these declarations all error with the following when I compile my project.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(38): error C2039: 'isalnum': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(38): error C2873: 'isalnum': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(39): error C2039: 'isalpha': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(39): error C2873: 'isalpha': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(40): error C2039: 'iscntrl': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(40): error C2873: 'iscntrl': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(41): error C2039: 'isdigit': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(41): error C2873: 'isdigit': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(42): error C2039: 'isgraph': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(42): error C2873: 'isgraph': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(43): error C2039: 'islower': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(43): error C2873: 'islower': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(44): error C2039: 'isprint': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(44): error C2873: 'isprint': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(45): error C2039: 'ispunct': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(45): error C2873: 'ispunct': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(46): error C2039: 'isspace': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(46): error C2873: 'isspace': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(47): error C2039: 'isupper': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(47): error C2873: 'isupper': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(48): error C2039: 'isxdigit': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(48): error C2873: 'isxdigit': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(49): error C2039: 'tolower': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(49): error C2873: 'tolower': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(50): error C2039: 'toupper': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(50): error C2873: 'toupper': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(52): error C2039: 'isblank': is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\cctype(52): error C2873: 'isblank': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
```

The result is the same with both c++11 and c++14. I attempted to make a minimal working example but could not because my toy project that includes and uses `<cctype>` compiles without problems. Therefore it must be a problem with my project settings somewhere.

I know this is going to be a tough one, but does anybody have any thoughts on what might be happening here?

Comment: In that header file, is the `_CSTD` macro properly defined? (It should be equivalent to `::`). I think this will involve some detective-style tracking down of the origin of the error.

Comment: Tough one - how about looking at the the pre-processor output?

Comment: @AdrianMole I tried to manually replace the macro with regular namespace declaration but I can't modify any of visual studio source files, even as administrator.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm working on it. I tried using the same library from a toy executable and annoyingly it worked. Therefore to look at the pre-processor output I have to compile the main project and sieve through the output.

Comment: (a) Look for reserved #defines and header guards with non-unique names (such that headers get excluded when they should not). (b) Checkout the last good build, role it forwards until the build breaks (binary chop if required); hopefully this will give you less to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on the macOS platform; the solution for me was to `#include <_ctype.h>` - this header defines the is* functions.